# Using UISearchDisplayController within a VC that is wrapped in a custom container VC

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to use a standard UISearchDisplayController within a VC that is wrapped in a custom container VC, that is in turn wrapped in a standard UINavigationController.

i.e:

```
 UINavigationController  
   MyCustomContainer  
     UITableViewController (making use of UISearchDisplayController)
```

Trying to make the nav bar move up and hide as per normal when the searchbox gets focus. However it doesn't do anything. Trying to forcefully do it using `[localNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` works for the hide, but during the show everything goes crazy (the table results view flickers, the original tableview doesn't scroll back down, etc).

This is all iOS7. Has anyone used UISearchDisplayControllers before within custom container VCs?